# agregar columnas despues de otra en postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

quisiera saber si hay una forma de
agregar columnas despues despues una una cierta columna en postgre, como en mysql que se aria de esta manera

```
alter table personal add capital int not null after nom;
```

quisiera saber si hay alguna manera en postgresql

Comment: La respuesta es no, como bien respondió @amenadiel. Pero toma en cuenta que, si sigues la mejores prácticas de siempre especificar de forma explícita las columnas que empleas en tus sentencias `SELECT` o `INSERT`, entonces no tiene mayor importancia el orden de las columnas en tu tabla.

Comment: ok, gracias, solo era para tener en orden las columns  y no confundirme despues

Answer (score 1):

No se puede. En postgres las columnas nuevas siempre van al final.

[Según la wiki, hay dos workarounds](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Alter_column_position):

- Recrear la tabla
- Añadir N columnas auxiliares (dejando tu columna nueva entre ellas, en la posición deseada), copiar la data a esas columnas auxiliares, y borrar las columnas originales.

Como verás, ninguna de las dos soluciones es muy bonita.

Answer (score 0):

Si la tabla no tiene información solo trunca y crea de nuevo en el orden que deseas que estén los campos.
Si la tabla tiene muchos registros, crea una nueva tabla auxiliar y pasa la información a esta nueva tabla auxiliar, trunca la tabla que no tiene el orden los campos y crea de nuevo en el orden que necesitas, pasa los registros de la tabla auxiliar a la tabla ya con las columnas ordenadas, trunca la tabla auxiliar, listo.